# How to lock screen orientation when anctivity isn't recreated

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

I have an activity used to display a video (VideoView).
By default the user can change screen orientation to see the video.
I avoid destroying/recreating the activity upon orientation changes because of latency issue.
The rotation is painless without any sound break.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

What I want to do now is add a button that will force the activity to remain on current orientation.

The problem is that because the activity isn't recreated after the rotation, I don't know which method to override to avoid the rotation to happen.
Overriding onConfigurationChanged is useless because the rotation already happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setRequestedOrientation()`.

E.g. to lock the orientation to portrait, call:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

In your activity.